# How can I map a hostname (subdomain) to Docker Container with Traefik?

Tags: docker, nginx, traefik

I have multiple Docker containers running nginx that serves up a web application. These containers are running on a virtual machine abc.com. They all require https.

If I have just one container running, I can access the container running at abc.com:443 no problem. I can also run multiple containers using docker run and port mapping where I can map a port to 433 like this:

```
VersionA          0.0.0.0:5000->443             can hit on abc.com:5000
VersionB          0.0.0.0:5001->443             can hit on abc.com:5001
VersionC          0.0.0.0:5002->443             can hit on abc.com:5002
```

What I would like is:

```
vA.abc.com -> VersionAContainer:443
vB.abc.com -> VersionBContainer:443
vC.abc.com -> VersionCContainer:443
```

These containers will spin up and close regularly and need them to be picked up by Traefik. What is the proper build command for traefik and run command for the container using labels?

This is how I was running the Traefik container with no luck.

```
sudo docker container run -d --name traefik_proxy \
    --network traefik_webgateway \
    -p 80:80 \
    -p 443:443 \
    -p 8080:8080 \
    --restart always \
    --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    --volume /dev/null:/traefik.toml \
    traefik --docker --logLevel=INFO --api \
        --entrypoints="Name:http Address::80 Redirect.EntryPoint:https" \
        --entrypoints="Name:https Address::443 TLS" \
        --defaultentrypoints="http,https"
```

And this is how I was running my container:

```
sudo docker run -d --name some-nginx \
    --network traefik_webgateway \
    --label traefik.docker.network=traefik_webgateway \
    --label traefik.protocol=https \
    --label traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https \
    --label traefik.frontend.rule=Host:something.localhost \ # unsure if this is correct to use local host or abc.com
    --label traefik.port=443 \
    --label traefik.frontend.auth.forward.tls.insecureSkipVerify=true \
    container:latest
```

Comment: Did you try the commands listed? Did they work? If not, what errors did you encounter?

Comment: @BMitch Yes. Running the above commands and then hitting something.abc.com results in this site cant be reached, IP address not found in the browser.

Comment: Did you configure DNS for the hostname to point to your docker host?

Comment: @BMitch Im pretty sure it already does given the fact that I can hit abc.com:433 and it hits my docker container on 443. Unless Im misunderstanding.

Comment: From what you've described, it's not clear what problem you're experiencing. You're talking directly to a docker container in one comment but can't resolve the IP in another.